# outputting queues in correct order

Tags: c++, queue

Working on outputting either a real number or integer number
i'm reading in a number character by character from a file. It will read an integer and push it into integerQueue up until it reaches a '.', then it will switch to inputting it into a realQueue.

Then when i print, it needs to print out  i.e.  Real:    123.4343

But right now the output is     Real:   123.   Integer 4343

Somehow my while loop or my  if statement isn't doing its job. I just can't find my error

question is, How do I fix my output so that it prints out 123.4343

```
    //if the realQueue is empty, then we just read in an integer, currentState must be 1, in order to print integer
            if(realQueue.empty() || currentState == '1')//implementation of the FSM
            {
                    writeFile <<"Integer:       ";
                    while(!integerQueue.empty())
                    {
                    writeFile <<integerQueue.front();
                    integerQueue.pop();
                    }
            }
            //since the realQueue has values in it, then it must bea real Number
            else
            {
                //currentState = '2';
                // currentState must be == '2', since wwe have a real number to print

                    writeFile<<"Real:           ";
                        //currentState has to be in real mode for it to print out to file
                        while(!integerQueue.empty() && currentState == '2')
                        {
                        writeFile <<integerQueue.front();
                        integerQueue.pop();
                        }
                        // currentState has to be in real mode for it to print out to file
                        while(!realQueue.empty() && currentState == '2')
                        {
                        writeFile <<realQueue.front();
                        realQueue.pop();
                        }

            }
```

Comment: How do i print out correctly 123.4242

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try comminting this loop out and see what happens.

```
while(!integerQueue.empty() && currentState == '2') 
{ 
  writeFile <<integerQueue.front(); 
  integerQueue.pop(); 
}
```

Comment: it prints out real: . and integer:   1234242      So it's not putting the period where its suppose to go

Comment: Thats not the way you answer a question. Explain the solution, provide further references and correct code. thats how SO works.