# printing queues in a specific order

Tags: c++, queue

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [outputting queues in correct order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740900/outputting-queues-in-correct-order)

I have two queues containing digits, integerQueue contains integers only, realQueue contains the beginning '.' then the following digits.

i need to print out the integer queue if only integers have been read in
but if realqueue has data in it,  i need to print out the first half integerqueu then the second half realqueu to make a real number like 123.234

currently my code will print   real  1.  then it will print integer:   2342343

How can i fix this so that the correct output is displayed?

```
//if the realQueue is empty, then we just read in an integer, currentState must be 1, in order to print integer
if(realQueue.empty() || currentState == '1')//implementation of the FSM
{
    writeFile <<"Integer:       ";
    while(!integerQueue.empty())
    {
        writeFile <<integerQueue.front();
        integerQueue.pop();
    }
}
//since the realQueue has values in it, then it must bea real Number
else
{
    //currentState = '2';
    // currentState must be == '2', since we have a real number to print

    writeFile<<"Real:           ";
    //currentState has to be in real mode for it to print out to file
    /*while(!integerQueue.empty() && currentState == '2')
    {
        writeFile <<integerQueue.front();
        integerQueue.pop();
    }*/
    // currentState has to be in real mode for it to print out to file
    while(!realQueue.empty() && currentState == '2' && !integerQueue.empty())
    {
        writeFile <<integerQueue.front()<<realQueue.front();

        integerQueue.pop();
        realQueue.pop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the `integerQueue` contains the digits before the '.', and the `realQueue` contains the digits after the '.', if any.
So if you find anything in your `realQueue`, you have a real number, otherwise an integer.

Correct?

In that case you don't even need to know the `currentState`:
just print the integer part

```
while( !integerQueue.empty() ) {
    writeFile << integerQueue.front();
    integerQueue.pop();
}
```

and then, if you have a real part as well, print that just behind the integer part:

```
while( !realQueue.empty() ) {
    writeFile << realQueue.front();
    realQueue.pop();
}
```